# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - objc - Click To Rate App Crash

Tags: c++, ios

I am trying to debug a crash with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0).  The problem occurs after a view appears with two buttons, to rate the app now or later.  If either the Rate or Later button is clicked, the crash occurs, at the same line in the code.

I am still learning Swift and know little to nothing about C++ or else I think I could work through this.  I am aware this is a memory issue, however.  I have not been able to find any zombies, so I have been looking through the code (which I did not write) to attempt to find what is missing or coming up vacant.  Since pressing Later causes the crash as well, I am thinking there is something missing or twisted up when trying to dismiss the view.

The error message in Xcode points to here at the beginning of the if statement:

```
if (menuItem->getTag()) {
    NativeBridge::rateApp();

    UserDefault::getInstance()->setBoolForKey("rate", true);
    UserDefault::getInstance()->flush();
}
```

menuItem is showing as NULL in the variable list on the error report.

The only instance of menuItem in the class is found a line just above the error:

```
MenuItemImage *menuItem = dynamic_cast<MenuItemImage*>(pSender);
```

The class where this is located can be found here: https://github.com/mrbradshaw5/swimfree/blob/master/GameScene.cpp

Any help is greatly appreciated!

As this is also my first post here, please let me know what other information I need to provide.

**Update**

I believe the error is coming from this block of code, which doesn't have the sprite needed.  menuItem is of type MenuItemSprite and both instances of menuItem are NULL.

```
#pragma mark -- show rate view
void GameScene::showRateView()
{
if (UserDefault::getInstance()->getBoolForKey("rate")) return;

Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

MenuItem *disableLayer = MenuItemSprite::create(LayerColor::create(Color4B(0, 0, 0, 0)), NULL, NULL);
Menu *menu = Menu::create(disableLayer, NULL);
menu->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT);
menu->setPosition(origin.x + visibleSize.width*0.5, origin.y + visibleSize.height*0.5);
menu->setTag(1111);
this->addChild(menu, 100);

LayerColor *m_pRateLayer = LayerColor::create(Color4B(0, 0, 0, 77), visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height);
m_pRateLayer->setTag(1112);
m_pRateLayer->retain();

Sprite *pBg = Sprite::create("bg_rate.png");
pBg->setPosition(origin.x + visibleSize.width*0.5, origin.y + visibleSize.height*0.5);
m_pRateLayer->addChild(pBg);

float bgW = pBg->getContentSize().width, bgH = pBg->getContentSize().height;

MenuItem *pRate = MyWidget::createMenuItemSpriteFrameName("button_rate.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onPressRateCallback, this));
pRate->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0.5));
pRate->setTag(1);
pRate->setPosition(Vec2(pBg->getPositionX() - 0.45 * bgW , pBg->getPositionY() - bgH / 2));

MenuItem *pLater = MyWidget::createMenuItemSpriteFrameName("button_later.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onPressRateCallback, this));
pLater->setTag(0);
pLater->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(1, 0.5));
pLater->setPosition(Vec2(pBg->getPositionX() + 0.45 * bgW, pBg->getPositionY() - bgH / 2));

Menu *pMenu = Menu::create(pRate, pLater, NULL);
pMenu->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);
pMenu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
m_pRateLayer->addChild(pMenu);

this->addChild(m_pRateLayer, 100);    
}
```

psender is created here

```
void GameScene::onPressRateCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender)
{
this->getChildByTag(1111)->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
this->getChildByTag(1112)->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

which leads to where menuItem is created.

```
MenuItemImage *menuItem = dynamic_cast<MenuItemImage*>(pSender);
```

and then to the line which throws the error

```
if (menuItem->getTag()) {
    NativeBridge::rateApp();

    UserDefault::getInstance()->setBoolForKey("rate", true);
    UserDefault::getInstance()->flush();
}
}
```

Error is thrown at the if statement.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: This is C++ not Objective-C

Comment: @vadian Oops... edited to reflect.

Comment: We would pretty much have to know where menuItem comes from.  The failure is caused by that being nil, and the question is why it is nil.

Comment: @dgatwood I edited the question to show were menuItem is in the class.  That is only place, it is found, one line above the if statement that failed.